# rails chartkick x axis no label only "..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am using rails Rails 5.1.5 with the gem chartkick

I want to plot a column graph. My code is as follows :

```
    <%= column_chart @communes %>
```

I get the correct numbers but the labels on the x axis are absent.
I only get three .

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1arL7YfTG3Cmqx6Q0_mcVZ4NO25vwkP-H

If I use any other chart, everything works and I have the axis properly labeled.
for example with

```
     <%= line_chart @communes %>
```

I get

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hK-LcPQSJsTbQqAxEa__qLBhMd4vJ3cf

Can someone explain to me what is the proper way to call the column_chart?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question for if someone runs
into the same problem.

There seems to be a bug the gem chartkick if you use Chart.js.

Just use Google Charts or Highcharts and everything will work